# How to apply perturbed metric in xPert calculations?

Tags: xact

I am using xAct (xTras and xPert) for doing linear perturbations. I almost know how to constrct the perturbed equations while I dont know how to apply the perturbed metric in the final equations. I also know that using MetricInBasis one can apply the background metric, lets say g, in equations and I am going to ask if there is something similar for the perturbed metric?